# NiFi URL not accessible on chrome

Tags: apache-nifi

There are several articles on NiFi secure cluster setup and ldap integration.
After following Pierre Villard's [Integration of NiFi with ldap](https://pierrevillard.com/2017/01/24/integration-of-nifi-with-ldap/) and Bryan Bende's [Authorization and Multitenancy](https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy) I'm able to run a secure nifi cluster which works seemlessly from firefox browser.

But, when I access the same url from chrome, i get the following error:

> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from xyz.abcd.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED

I haven't generated any user certificates because LDAP login is expected which actually works fine with firefox. Is there anything extra that needs to be done for chrome which firefox actually doesn't require? The issue has been same from all the users who are using chrome to authenticate into my cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Chrome after version 56 enforces stronger certificate validation. In addition, Chrome uses the OS keychain, while Firefox provides its own. So you may have marked the generated server certificate as trusted within Firefox but this would not translate to Chrome. Is there a text link below that message to go into "Advanced Settings" or similar?

Depending on how you generated this certificate, check that it has not expired, it was not actually revoked by the issuing CA, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've just checked the server certificate being received. It says the following: Expires on: Aug 22, 2020
Current date: Aug 29, 2017. Based on this, I don't think it has expired. Is there a way to make this generated certificate as trusted and proceed ?

Comment: Run the command line tool `s_client` as follows: `$ openssl s_client -connect host:port -showcerts -state -debug` where `host:port` is your NiFi instance (i.e. `localhost:8443`). The output should end with a status code. `0` is good. `19` or `21` are common errors for *self-signed* or *unsigned* certificates. *Certificate revoked* is `23`.

Comment: It was hard for me to get openssl installed on my corporate machine due to permissions. But, importing certificate from firefox to chrome did the trick. Thanks for the answers. They helped me understand the workings of NiFi.